# Can't authenticate to Skype For Business Online UCWA

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I'm having trouble authenticating to S4BO. I have registered my app (in azure portal) and it's working correclty with the webSDK demo at https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk
The process I follow is the following one:

1. I do a OAuth link redirect with the following code:

   ```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com&redirect_uri=http://myurl.dev/skype
   ```
2. Get the auth code that has been returned and use it to generate an access token:

   ```
   POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=db01d1f5-f2a3-4d82-b4bc-6b3b4071d7df&resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com&redirect_uri=http://acme.intranet.dev/skype

        grant_type=authorization_code
        code=$thecodehere
        client_id=$clientidhere
        client_secret=$clientsecrethere
        redirect_uri=$sameuriasbefore
   ```
3. After this I have my access token. Now I need my user url. So I do autodiscover

   ```
   GET https://lyncdiscover.mydomain.onmicrosoft.com
   ```

and I receive a result something like:

```
{
"_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root?originalDomain=mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    "user": {
      "href": "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    "xframe": {
      "href": "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame.html"
    }
  }
}
```

4. I try to log in at the user url:

   ```
   GET https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=mydomain.onmicrosoft.com
   HEADERS:
   Authorization: Bearer + theAccessTokenFromAbove
   Referer: https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame.html
   ```

And after this I get 403 Unathorized. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It is more complicated than what you have above.  You have an access token for the user to O365.  You would then need to login in to Skype for Business Online using those credentials and finally get the oauth token that UCWA could use to get authorization past Autodiscovery.

Comment: Can you tell me or point me to a resource that shows how to do that? I can't for my life figure it out from the documentation they have.

Comment: Specifically, I'm not sure how to do this in a scenario where my web app server should be able to schedule meetings in the users behalf, even when the user is not logged in to the site ( so I should have access when the user is not on my site).

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Get the auth code that has been returned and use it to generate an access token

On this step as a resource you need to specify `resource=https://webdir1e.online.lync.com` (notice **1e**) to get access to this particular hub.

Actually you will have to authenticate on every new server starting from this point, so on all the webdirXX and then on the webpoolXXXXX.

I wrote a huge interactive article that describes the requests flow in detail (after myself spending a week to reverse engineer how outlook.com does that because MSDN documentation is - at least at the time of writing this - incomplete and incorrect), maybe it can be of use:

- https://markeev.com/posts/skype4b/

If you configure app redirect URL to the article URL (temporarily of course), you can even test the queries right from there.

Additionally, autodiscovery and authentication code "in one piece" can be found on Github (with live demo):

- https://github.com/andrei-markeev/skype4b